# Swift let property set through prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, properties, segue, option-type

In Objective-C I can very easily add a property to a `.h` file ...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *person;
```

and then set this property during `prepareForSegue:withIdentifier:`.

In this example, the class of the view controller is `PersonViewController`. It is designed to show information about a particular `Person` object. It needs a `Person` object to display anything and the `Person` object will not change. To display a different person that would require and pop and push to a different instance of `PersonViewController`.

This, to me, would suggest that in Swift the `person` property should be defined like so...

```
let person: Person
```

except it can't be. If I set it this way then it has to be initialised before the end of the `init` method... But there is no way of doing this as it is being instantiated by the `Storyboard`.

So I could do this...

```
var person: Person?
```

except this is wrong. The `PersonViewController` will not work without a `person` so making it optional doesn't make sense and making it a `var` doesn't make sense either as the `person` will not change.

Additionally to this I have to add...

```
guard let person = person else {return}
```

to every function where I need to use the `person` object.

I could do it this way...

```
var person = Person()
```

but this feels hacky and wasteful. Every time I create the view controller I now create and then throw away a `Person`. It's also a var which doesn't make sense in the context of the view controller.

What is the best way to do the equivalent thing of passing in a property during a segue where the property is not optional, is not `var` and is not created during the init?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the best way to do it is declare it as:

```
var person: Person!
```

If you are sure that the person object will be always set it saves you a time with unwrapping optional.

I afraid that you cannot declare it as let because this property will be set after the class will be initialised.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense I guess. It's a shame though that it still has to be a `var`. Thanks

Comment: It's the better approach but still don't solve the problem of @Fogmeister, it could be an interesting approach to propose because really doesn't exist something to simulate this behavior